# NavigationBar height changing on coming back to Portrait orientation

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios9

I have a structure as follows:

> **ContainerView** --embed segue--> **NavigationController** --> **UITableViewController A** --push segue--> **UITableViewController B**

This arrangement works fine, but when I change the orientation to **Landscape**, tap on a row in **A** which takes me to **B**, and change the orientation back to **Portrait**, my NavigationBar height increases as below:

**1) Portrait mode, all good:**

[image]

**1) Orientation changed to Landscape mode, all good:**

[image]

**3) Tapped on a row while in Landscape mode, all good:**

[image]

**4) Back to Portrait Mode, Navigation Bar taller than usual!** 
[image]

I don't have any code in any of the `viewDidLoad()`,`viewWillAppear()`,`viewDidAppear()` etc which does ANY change in the layout or the constraints. In the storyboard, I have tried the `Adjust ScrollView Insets` on and off without any luck. What could be wrong?

**Update:** This does not happen if I do not use the `ContainerView`. So that seems to be the culprit. I am not using my own class for the ContainerView or the view which contains it. The constraints to it are pretty straight forward: Leading, Trailing space to SuperView and Bottom, Top to Bottom Layout Guide and Top Layout Guide respectively. Could this be a bug with `ContainerView` itself?

Comment: Have you used any constraints or AutoLayout?

Comment: Not on the NavigationBar (not sure if that's possible), but for the other elements on the view, yes I have. There are no constraints where I am hardcoding the height though.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure if that is possible either, but I am just trying to think of things that would mess with the height (apart from simple Xcode bugs of course).

Comment: Same here, I have been at this for over a day now and not making any progress. If I don't change the orientation, no problem all is good. I also made sure that I am not doing anything by myself when the orientation changes..sigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out what the problem was. When I had put the `ContainerView` in the `View` of the `UIViewController` in the storyboard, I had aligned the **top** edge of the `ContainerView` to the **bottom** edge of the `StatusBar`. That's how I set the constraint as well. That was the root of the issue. Once I changed it so that **top** edges of `ContainerView` and `StatusBar` were **aligned**, the issue was resolved!